# Initialization Of Connection String In WinForm And In UserControl

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, user-controls, connection-string

See the Coding below:

```
**Application Config File**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key ="Mystring" value ="server=MyServer;Initial Catalog 
MyDataBase;uid=MYUID;pwd=MYPWD"/>
</appSettings>

</configuration>


**Connection Code:**

string connstr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mystring"]; 
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
con.Open();
```

I have tested it at WinApplication and in Windows Control Library(UserControl) and found that the above code works in WinApplication and the same is not in Windows Control Library instead it throw exception like  **” Connection string has not been Initialized”**

If SQL assembly present in both VS application then Is it reasionable exception In Winows Control Library?.

What is the Solution?.

Comment: Why are you using `appSettings` instead of the built in `connectionStrings` configuration section?

Comment: How are you executing the control library?

Comment: @Oded, By pressing f5 function key

Comment: The control library is a DLL. It cannot be set as the startup project. What kind of project is the startup project that loads the control library and executes it?

Comment: @Oded, Yes you are right that control library is a DLL Application but it can be test by executing function key f5 and you will get it that whether your code is executable or not if it is executable then you will apply it to your startup project like WinApplication and I do the same.

Comment: Hope you know about simplest form (I am telling because I did not know this simple way for a long time:p ) `string connstr = "MyString"; SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);` It is not much professional (does not facilitate encryption) but it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a test project, you need to add the settings (app.config file) there.

If you are debugging directly, DEVENV creates a sample app that host user control, you need to need to read the settings explicitly.

You can use [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691098%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to differentiate whether user control debugging by DEVENV, or by hosting in under app.

Code like

```
  #ifdef RunningUnderHost
  // read app settings
  #endif
```

RunningUnderHost can be defined over library, and not over app.

Comment: Sorry but it's not my question's answer